# Changing SynchronizationContext Within Async Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I am trying to post a lean question here, without code, because my question is so specific: Is it possible/acceptable to modify the **SynchronizationContext** within an Async method? If I don't set **SynchronizationContext** when the Async method begins, it seems that code within it--including events I raise and methods within the same class module I call--run on the same worker thread. However, when it comes time to interact with the UI, I find that the **SynchronizationContext** has to be set to the UI thread.

Is it okay to keep the **SynchronizationContext** set to the worker thread until such time that I want to invoke a call to a UI-based function?

EDIT:
To further clarify my above question, I find myself in a no-win situation with respect to the SynchronizationContext setting. If don't set the SynchronizationContext then my async operations run on a separate thread (as desired) but then I can't return data to the UI thread without encountering a cross-thread operation exception; if I set the SynchronizationContext to my UI thread then the operations I want to run on a separate thread end up running on the UI thread--and then (of course) I avoid the cross-thread exception and everything works. Clearly, I'm missing something.

If you care to read more, I've tried to provide a very clear explanation of what I'm trying to do and I realize you're investing your time to understand so thank you for that!

What I'm trying to do is shown in this flow diagram:

[image]

I have a Winforms application running on the UI thread (in black); I have a Socket object I'd like to run on its own thread. The job of the socket class is to read data from a communication socket and raise events back to the UI whenever data arrives.

Note that I start a message loop from the UI thread so that the socket is continually polled for data on its own thread; if data is received, I want to process that data synchronously on the same non-UI thread before grabbing any more data from the socket. (Yes, if something goes awry with any particular socket read, the socket might be left with unread data in it.)

The code to start the message loop looks like this:

```
if (Socket.IsConnected)
{
   SetUpEventListeners();
   // IMPORTANT: next line seems to be required in order to avoid a cross-thread error
   SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());
   Socket.StartMessageLoopAsync();
}
```

When I start the message loop from the UI thread, I call an async method on the `Socket` object:

```
 public async void StartMessageLoopAsync()
  {
     while (true)
     {
        // read socket data asynchronously and populate the global DataBuffer
        await ReadDataAsync();

        if (DataBuffer.Count == 0)
        {
           OnDataReceived();
        }
     }
  }
```

The `Socket` object also has the `OnDataReceived()` method defined as:

```
  protected void OnDataReceived()
  {
     var dataEventArgs = new DataEventArgs();
     dataEventArgs.DataBuffer = DataBuffer;

     // *** cross-thread risk here!
     DataReceived?.Invoke(this, dataEventArgs);
  }
```

I have highlighted two areas of the diagram with "1" and "2" blue stars.

In "1" (on the diagram), I am using the async/await pattern. I am using a third-party socket tool that doesn't support Async, so I have wrapped that in my own `ReadDataAsync()` function that looks like this:

```
  public override async Task ReadDataAsync()
  {
     // read a data asynchronously
     var task = Task.Run(() => ReadData());
     await task;
  }
```

`ReadData()` wraps the third-party component's read method: it populates a global data buffer, so no return value is needed.

In "2" in the diagram, I am encountering the cross-thread risk described in my `OnDataReceived()` method cited above.

Bottom Line: If I set `SynchronizationContext` as shown in my first code clip above, then everything in the Socket object runs on its own thread until I try to invoke the DataReceived event handler; if I comment-out the `SynchronizationContext` then the only part of the code that runs on its own thread is the brief third-party socket-read operation wrapped in my `DataReadAsync()` method.

So my thought was whether I can set the `SynchronizationContext` just ahead of trying to invoke the DataReceived event handler. And even if I "can", the better question is whether this is a good idea. If I do modify `SynchronizationContext` within the non-UI thread then I'd have to set it back to its original value after invoking the DataReceived method, and that has a Durian-like code-smell to me.

Is there an elegant tweak to my design or does it need an overhaul? My goal is to have all red items in the diagram running on a non-UI thread and the black items running on the UI thread. "2" is the point at which the non-UI thread my cross over to the UI thread...

Thank you.

Comment: Anything is possible, however the question does seem a little.. well.. suspect. There are plenty of mechanism to post back to the UI. the easiest being the async await pattern and letting it propagate from the UI, though there are many more depending on what you are doing and how. What is the actual use case here?

Comment: Yes, I figured more information would be needed. I'll post a more complete question because what I'm really trying to do is prevent the async method from getting back to the UI thread until I specifically want it to. When I set the SynchronizationContext ahead of the async method call then the async method ends up back on the UI thread when I invoke certain members, and I don't want it to do that. Clearly, I need to rethink the design. Thanks for weighing in. +1

Comment: OK, I updated the question. You might be sorry you asked about the use case... :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting context directly isn't the best idea since other functionality being occasionally executed in this thread can be affected. The most natural way to control synchronization context for `async/await` flows is using `ConfigureAwait`. So in your case I see two options to achieve what you want:

**1)** Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` with `ReadDataAsync`

```
public async void StartMessageLoopAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // read socket data asynchronously and populate the global DataBuffer
        await ReadDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (DataBuffer.Count == 0)
        {
            OnDataReceived();
        }
    }
}
```

which will make resuming everything after await in background thread. And then use `Dispatcher` `Invoke` to marshal `DataReceived?.Invoke` into UI thread:

```
protected void OnDataReceived()
{
   var dataEventArgs = new DataEventArgs();
   dataEventArgs.DataBuffer = DataBuffer;

   // *** cross-thread risk here!
   Dispatcher.CurrentDispathcer.Invoke(() => { DataReceived?.Invoke(this, dataEventArgs ); });
}
```

Or **2)** Make some logic decomposition like as follows:

```
    public async void StartMessageLoopAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // read socket data asynchronously and populate the global DataBuffer
            await ProcessDataAsync();

            // this is going to run in UI thread but there is only DataReceived invocation
            if (DataBuffer.Count == 0)
            {
                OnDataReceived();
            }
        }
    }
```

`OnDataReceived` is thin now and does only event triggering

```
    protected void OnDataReceived()
    {
        // *** cross-thread risk here!
        DataReceived?.Invoke(this, dataEventArgs);
    }
```

This consolidates the functionality supposed to run in background thread

```
    private async Task ProcessDataAsync()
    {
        await ReadDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // this is going to run in background thread
        var dataEventArgs = new DataEventArgs();
        dataEventArgs.DataBuffer = DataBuffer;
    }

    public override async Task ReadDataAsync()
    {
        // read a data asynchronously
        var task = Task.Run(() => ReadData());
        await task;
    }
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I ran into an unrelated tech issue at work that's occupying all of my time. I will mark your response as the answer once I integrate it. That might not be until next week now--thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a scenario better served with reactive extensions:

[Reactive Extensions for .NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive)

Comment: Maybe, but I'm really trying to solve this using async/await and my own programming. But I will read more about these extensions for future use--what I saw so far look very interesting. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: `async-await` is pull and Rx is push. Events are push.